# How can I feature-detect Microsoft’s css `filter` ActiveX controls?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, activex

Is it possible to see if an MSIE `filter` rule was applied?

Note: I know about IE conditional comments and the like, but those are, strictly speaking, UA detection if not outright browser sniffing, and I prefer feature detection (as a standard best practice, and especially in this case).

(Please also do not waste time telling me these properties aren’t standard CSS, etc. I know. Trust me that this is a pragmatic move to better support our IE users.)

Comment: It might make more sense to detect whether the *feature you need to replace* (using a `filter`) is available. Take `opacity` as an example. If the CSS property `opacity` is not supported, you can assume it's old IE and you need to use the `filter` variant.

Comment: In general, perhaps, thirtydot. But not always: consider the case of showing an arbitrary image in grayscale, client-side; you can do it in `canvas`, or with a `filter`; not quite 100% of browsers support either… and maybe in IE9, `filter` is faster, anyway — I’d want to check.

Comment: Well, as an example [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/desaturate/) uses `canvas` if it's available, otherwise it uses `filter` (or else then it fails). http://www.pixastic.com/lib/git/pixastic/actions/desaturate.js

Comment: FYI: That link results in `403 Forbidden` unless you refresh it (I assume you are checking `Referer`s to prevent hotlinking).

Comment: Technically, Pixastic *attempts to use* `filter` if `canvas` is not available, but there is no way to be completely sure. It’s still browser detection. Can’t users opt to turn off ActiveX? Do filters still run? Might filters be faster than `canvas` in IE9?

Comment: Speaking *pragmatically*, I wouldn't bother thinking about the minuscule percentage of users that use IE *and* somehow have `filter` disabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test for css properties like modernizr.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417968/how-to-test-for-css-properties-like-modernizr-js)