# How to test for css properties like modernizr.js

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr

I would like to test if a browser supports a CSS property. I know I can use modernizr to do this but I don't want to install an entire library to test for one property.

How does modernizr test for properties? Say I want to test for support for the background-size property.

I scanned through the properties of the document object but couldn't see anything that looked like it would help.

Any ideas or help would be great.

Comment: You don't install an entire library with modernizer, you click the choices and install only what you want to test for.

Comment: Did you take a look at modernizer's implementation? THat would be my first attempt...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modernizr works by creating an element, applying a css property and then checking the return value of the css property. For example, if you wanted to test for text shadow you would do this:

```
if (document.createElement("detect").style.textShadow === "") {
    document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className += " textshadow";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think think this will be specific to each feature since you have to look for certain side effects in the DOM. Here is a link with some ideas http://www.sitepoint.com/detect-css3-property-browser-support/

Answer (score -1):

Modernizr is an open source project - you can literally view the code that powers it. [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/backgroundsize.js) is background-size detect specifically.

This is a fairly trivial thing to check. You create a dom element, set `background-size` (both vanilla and all of the vendor prefixed versions) to `100%`, and then check the value of backgroundSize on the dom element's style property to see if it kept that value.

That being said - modernizr is pretty lean. You just get the tests you want, and nothing more.

Comment: I think what the OP is asking is how do you test for a specific css property without modernizr.

Comment: I understand that - that is what I explain in the second paragraph.